# How to use ADB shell to find the ports which a process is using?

Tags: android, linux, port, adb, netstat

For example, in Android, the PID of a process 1234 is using ports 2222,2223,2224. Now I have a PID 1234. I was wondering how to find out port numbers 2222, 2223, 2224 which the process is using?

I have tried using netstat -anp just as the way in Linux, but that didn't work. netstat -anp in ADB shell has the same effect as just netstat, which is without any command arguments.

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120258/445908

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either use `busybox netstat -pt` or `cat /proc/1234/net/tcp`

Comment: This assumes that busybox is installed.

Comment: @Alex cat /proc/1234/net/tcp lists all the tcp sockets on the system, not just the sockets opened by process 1234.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check my github repository, https://github.com/LipiLee/netstat.

I updated toolbox's netstat in Android source code(<strike>https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/toolbox/netstat.c</strike>).

UPDATE: The toolbox's netstat was replaced with toybox's netstat in Android M version. So the netstat in toolbox was removed in the Android source tree.