# How to check whether a service in running on particular port using adb

Tags: android, android-service, adb

I have a third party application in my android phone.
The application offers a service at 127.0.0.1:30002.

I don't know the name of service.

Is there a way to find out whether that tcp service is up or not using adb or some other means.

Also what is the use of adb reverse.
Can i run a server in host pc and forward that server on android using adb reverse.

I am completely new to android, so please be brief.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To find which app using specific port:**

1. `$ cat /proc/net/tcp` - This will give you a list of open ports and the UId (unique application ID) of the port's owner.
2. `& cat /data/system/packages.list | grep '<The UID you just found>'` - This will give you the app name connected to this UID.
3. `ps |grep '<the app name>'` Will tell you if the app service is running.

**What is** `adb reverse`?

`adb reverse` tells your phone use a port of your local machine (e.g laptop).
Assume you use the command:

```
adb reverse tcp:80 tcp:3000
```

Now when your phone tries to access http://localhost:3000/ your request will be routed to localhost:80 of your laptop.

Comment: when I do adb reverse tcp:30002 tcp:30002 command executes, but adb reverse --list shows error: